# Georgia invitation letter for visa

Tags: visas, georgia-country, invitation-letters

My friend and I want to go to Georgia as tourists on Pakistani passports. I can enter Georgia without a visa on valid USA visa. However my friend needs a Georgia visa on his passport. He needs a invitation letter from Georgia could be from a travel agency. I contacted several travel agents online and none of them replied so far.

What would be the best possible source of getting a Georgian invitation letter from Georgia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Georgian visa, a legal resident, [a citizen of Georgia or a "legal entity" can send you the letter of invitation](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/en/faq/cid/21/id/74). If you don't know anyone in Georgia, a legal entity is a company, for example a registered hotel. The document has to be notarized and written in English or Georgian and sent with your application. [You'll find the forms at this link.](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=160&lang=Eng)

> An alien can be invited to Georgia either by the citizen of Georgia of
>   full legal age, with the capacity for rights, or by the person holding
>   a Georgian residence permit, or the legal entity, registered in
>   Georgia. An invitation shall be submitted to a visa issuing authority
>   as a notarized original or copy, to verify the fact of its
>   notarization through the web-page of LEPL Notary Chamber of Georgia.

Note that your friend could also be [eligible](https://www.evisa.gov.ge/GeoVisa/en/Home/FAQ) for an [eVisa](https://www.evisa.gov.ge/GeoVisa/) which doesn't require a letter of invitation. All they need is a travel Document/Passport, a photo and a credit/debit card, and it's not necessary to have supporting documents.

Comment: Any registered hotel which could arrange invitation letter for him

Comment: @AliAwan are you asking me if to recommend hotels that will do it or if any hotel can do it ?

Comment: @ blackbird I am asking any recommendations for a hotel that would arrange definitely so that I won't have to look further

Comment: @AliAwan I'm sorry, I don't know any hotels in Georgia. You could always write/call and ask, I'm sure you're not the first tourist to ask for such a letter.

Comment: @ blackbird it is really disappointing they never reply to my emails, looking really frustrating

Comment: @AliAwan that sucks. Do you know anyone who lives there ? Did your friend check out the evisa ?

Comment: @ blackbird I am fully aware of all visa requirements for him, I have checked the entire website and he apparently needs an invitation letter. I have already visited Georgia last year without a Georgia visa. If we couldn't get any reliable source, we would have to cancel Georgia trip eventually

Comment: @AliAwan this [website](http://exploreazerbaijan.com/visa/visa_to_georgia/) seems to offer a service that makes you one, I can't comment on its reliability though

Comment: @ blackbird I sent a request, let's see I get any reply

Comment: @AliAwan this [company](http://www.east-west-tours.com/georgia-visa) also seems to deliver LOI, I'm not sure they service Pakistan but you could always ask

Comment: @ blackbird for me 150$ is hell of a money just for an invitation, it is like at least 3 to 4 different consulates fees . I tell him now just apply there and let's see how they reply

Answer (score -4):

It might be hard for you two as people generally dont trust/give invitations easily, especially if you are coming from muslim country

If you can come here yourself, you might find someone who could help you out. Online transactions are still not popular and people prefer talking about it personally

Comment: So simply I should stop looking for invitation letter from Georgia?

Comment: I disagree with this answer. First what's your reference for saying they wouldn't deliver a LOI for Muslims ? Second, the OP cannot travel to Georgia because they need a visa which requires an LOI.

Comment: If he can enter Georgia without visa he could find someone who could send an invitation for his friend as well - I dont think this requires too much to think of. Second - With the recent influx of tourists from arabic countries and the acts of terrorism in turkey government is getting tighter on touristic sector and monitors heavily who is entering and exiting Georgia.

Comment: Your proposal doesn't sound very practical if they intend to travel together. LOI aren't delivered by the government but by citizens, if you meant visas then that's orthogonal to the question